# MySQL stored procedures - How to use parameter in FROM clause

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER ///

CREATE PROCEDURE tmp_test_proc(__TABLE__NAME varchar(255))
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM __TABLE__NAME;
END///

DELIMITER ;
```

I would like to select from the parameter `__TABLE__NAME`, but MySQL tells me there is no table `__TABLE__NAME`... So is there a way to use the value of the parameter in the from clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot parameterized table names (*as well as column names*) by default, you need to create `PreparedStatement` for this,

```
DELIMITER ///

CREATE PROCEDURE tmp_test_proc(__TABLE__NAME varchar(255))
BEGIN
    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ', __TABLE__NAME);

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END///

DELIMITER ;
```